# Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate batchUpdate with like clause

Tags: sql, spring

I am trying to a batchUpdate using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. Here's code:

```
SqlParameterSource[] batch = SqlParameterSourceUtils
                .createBatch(groupDTOList.toArray());
namedParamJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(roleSQLQuery, batch);

roleSQLQuery = UPDATE Role set Name=replace(Name, :name, :targetGroupName) where Name like %:name
```

name and targetGroupName are properties on the dto. It works on a different query without the like clause. How do I include a % infron of the named parameter? Thanks!

Here's how I got it to work. Let me know if anyone has a better idea...thanks

```
 roleSQLQuery = UPDATE Role set* Name=replace(Name, :name, :targetGroupName) where Name like :sourceName  
    for(DTO dto:groupDTOList){  
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    params.put("sourceName", "%"+ dto.getName() + "%");  
    roleParams.add(params);*  
    }  
    Map<String,String>[] ar= roleParams.toArray(new HashMap[roleParams.size()]);  
    int[] result = namedParamJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(roleSQLQuery, ar);
```

Comment: By adding it to the parameter not by adding it to the query. In this case you probably are going to need 2 parameters one for the plain `name` and one for the `like` clause

Comment: Since I am using SqlParameterSourceUtils's createBatch method, how would I control the parameters?

Comment: By adding them before creating the `SqlParameterSource[]`.

Comment: Could you show me some code? Sorry, I still didn't get it.